# How to clear input field without using onSubmit in React.js

Tags: reactjs, input, components, reset, use-state

> I tried resetting the input field by giving a value attribute to the input field but it gives a error like:
> value can be used only with onChange.
> Is there any method to reset the input field?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import List from "./List";
import "./Form.css";
import iconSun from "../images/icon-sun.svg";

const Form = (props) => {

const [input, setInput] =useState("")

  const inputHandler = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value)
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      const data = {
        name: input,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random().toFixed(4) * 10000).toString()
      }
        props.eventHandler(data)
    }
    setInput("")
  };

  return (

    <div className="toform">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>Todo</h1>
        <img src={iconSun} alt="" className="imgs" />
        <input type="text" onKeyPress={inputHandler} value={input} />
      </div>
      <List lists={props.name} />
    </div>
 );
};
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably means you need to add a `onChange` prop to the input that will listen to the changes of the `input` value to update the value

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  onKeyPress={inputHandler} 
  value={input} 
  onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value) 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This one worked but need to add one more code in inputHandler function In-order to reset the input field.

After setting onChange to event.target.value, we need to add setInput("") in inputHandler to fully reset 

const inputHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      const data = {
        name: input,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random().toFixed(4) * 10000).toString()
      }
        props.eventHandler(data)
        setInput("")
    }

Like this.

Thank you